# PHP/MySQL - Call to a member function query()

Tags: php, mysql, function

My Code worked fine until yet.
I dont know what's wrong.

```
public function maintenanceAll()
{
    $zeile = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM maintenance LIMIT 1');
    $row = $zeile->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$row['status']) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now only comes:

```
[Mon Mar 07 11:30:55.802597 2016] [:error] [pid 6064] [client 5.135.44.40:37955] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on string in /home/admin/web/creative-cube.biz/public_html/classes/User.class.php on line 145
```

I hope anyone can help me. :/

//Edit:

(Connection to database) DB.class.php:

```
class DB {
    public function connect()
    {
        global $Config; 

        try {
            return new PDO('mysql:host='.$Config["SQL_HOST"].';dbname='.$Config["SQL_DB"].'',''.$Config["SQL_USER"].'',''.$Config["SQL_PASS"].'');
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

User.class.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = new DB();
    $this->db = $this->db->connect();
}
```

Comment: how you are creating connection? show us

Comment: Please provide Connection code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. All other functions which are constructed similar to that function work fine.

Comment: @RayJohnson something is wrong.  Perhaps something being called before this is setting `$this->db` in a way you don't expect, and the error information says that the connection isn't what it's expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->db` isn't a database connection, it's a string. Check that your database connection is still working correctly. If your connection is still valid, make sure something isn't overwriting the `$this->db` variable.

EDIT:
Looking at the code you posted, there is a problem with the connection, it's returning the exception message, and that's being set to `$this->db`.

```
try {
    return new PDO('mysql:host='.$Config["SQL_HOST"].';dbname='.$Config["SQL_DB"].'',''.$Config["SQL_USER"].'',''.$Config["SQL_PASS"].'');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: But how can that be? On another Webserver it works perfectly. :/

Comment: Maybe on the other webserver the database IP, port, username, password etc is different. If you dump out `$this->db` and post the string it should give you some more info.

Comment: Alright. My database was not connected correctly. That's embarrassing. Thanks. ^^

Comment: No problem! I'd recommend you removing your answer to this post where you put the code, as it's not an answer, and instead edit it into your question at the top :).